# Custom class UI element Android

Tags: android

i am trying to add a CalendarCell that extends a TextView to the xml file, but i get this error : binary xml file, error inflating class

here is my code
**com.thinline.dm21.utils.CelluleHebdomadaire.java**

```
public class CelluleHebdomadaire extends TextView{
   public String date;
   public String heure;
   public CelluleHebdomadaire(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
   }
}
```

**res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="CelluleHebdomadaire">
      <attr name="distanceExample" format="dimension"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and my **layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:customNS="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.thinline.dm21.utils"
    android:id="@+id/layout_calendrierhebdomadaire"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BBBBBB">

  <com.thinline.dm21.utils.CelluleHebdomadaire
    android:id="@+id/Cellule_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Element..." />
</LinearLayout>
```

am i missing something ?

i have edited my post to match my actual code, the app is working, but the CalendrierCellule is not displayed

Comment: you post the code for CelluleHebdomadaire not for CalendrierCellule

Comment: If you look at the bottom of that exception it should tell you the reason. Your app's package is `com.thinline.dm21.utils`?

Comment: it is working, i had to change my background to white color, the celluleHebdomadaire was there

Answer (score 1):

The name of your custom class is CelluleHebdomadaire not CalendrierCellule as you've defined in the layout